# GL_LINE_STRIP and GL_POLYGON at same time OPENGL

Tags: java, opengl

I want to use wireframes and fill polygones at the same time, I'm using yellow and black colors so i can distinguish one from another

```
 gl1.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 gl1.glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
 gl1.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
 gl1.glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
```

But I am getting the following error: Info: GLDrawableHelper.reshape: pre-exisiting GL error 0x502

Well I guess it is because I can only use one glBegin(...) in some function , is there another way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. You only can draw a polygon type at any time. If you want a filled polygon and a line loop using the same vertices, you still have to draw two times.

> Well I guess it is because I can only use one glBegin(...) in some
>   function

You cannot nest `glBegin()` calls. Only a very small subsetof gl function is allowed inside a `glBegin/glEnd` block: basically, you can just set the current attributes for the vertices, and generate the vertices there. But you cann have as many `glBegin/glEnd` blocks in a function as you like.

I just have to remark that `glBegin/glEnd` is deprecated/removed in modern OpenGL versions, you shouldn't use this stuff nowadays without a very good reason to.

Comment: So it's only possible to use wirefreame and fill polygone at the same time if i draw it twice?

Comment: It can _never_ be used at the same time. One time you do the first, then you do the other.